# Access "Named Ranges" or "Document Properties" in MS Word

Tags: google-apps-script, ms-word, google-docs

Is there any way to access "Named Ranges" or "Document Properties" after we export google doc file to MS Word? or is there any other way to save some metaData inside google doc which can be used later after exporting the google doc in MS word?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Google Docs have something similar to this which is [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) that allows scripts to store strings as key-value pairs scoped to one script, one user of a script, or one document in which an editor add-on is used. Here are the Class Properties Methods you can use in PropertiesService.

- [PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html#getDocumentProperties())
- [PropertiesService.getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html#getUserProperties())
- [PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html#getScriptProperties())

See this following [guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) for more information about the extension mechanism.

Comment: thanks for your reply it was helpful but what i really wanted to ask was that can i access DocumentProperties after downloading Google Doc document as Microsoft Word Doc?